# function is_dir() in Linux

Tags: php, linux

The is_dir() function doesn't work in my linux system. The directory is as follow:

- /var

  - /www

    - /html
           - test.php
    - /code

`is_dir("/var/www/html")` returns true. But `is_dir("/var/www/code")` returns false.
All the directory is readable.
So why this happened?
Thanks all!

Addition:
The `safe_mode` in php is off. And the permission of html and code is same.
`(drwxr-xr-x root root)`

Comment: Do the permissions on "/var/www/code" differ from "/var/www/html"?

Comment: What's your safe_mode and open_basedir setting? What are the permissions of the html and code dirs?

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake when creating `code` maybe it's a file you just didn't put extension

Comment: @acctoff [does it work using `DirectoryIterator` along with `getType`? Something like this `$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname("/var/www/code")); foreach ($dir as $dirinfo) { echo $dirinfo->getFilename(), ' ', $dirinfo->getType(), "\n"; }`](http://br2.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.gettype.php)

Comment: `DirectoryIterator` is something diffent than `is_dir()`.

Comment: DirectoryIterator is not work either.

Answer (score 1):

From php manual:

> Note that on Linux is_dir returns FALSE if a parent directory does not
>   have +x (executable) set for the php process.